# Troubles with modules after upgrade to kernel 3.2.0-60

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dkms

Everything worked fine until kernel `3.2.0-58`. Then the update manager proposed an update to `3.2.0-59`, I did it but the update didn't finished successfully (I was able to boot but windows with error messages popped out continuously). So I uninstalled `3.2.0-59` in favour of `-58` again, which I'm currently using.

Today the update manager proposed to install kernel `3.2.0-60`, I said OK but still have problems. For example, wireless doesn't work anymore. I mean that the wifi led is red instead of blue and even pressing F12 doesn't help to activate the interface, which *is* recognized, though:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network -short
H/W path         Device   Class     Description
===============================================
/0/100/1c/0      eth0     network   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.1/0    eth1     network   BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

Trying to understand what happened I did a module diff between `-58` and `-60` and surprisingly I noted some modules are missing in `3.2.0-60`:

```
$ diff -u kernel-3.2.0-58 kernel-3.2.0-60 
--- kernel-3.2.0-58 2014-03-08 23:56:52.290500167 +0100
+++ kernel-3.2.0-60 2014-03-08 23:57:01.254500638 +0100
-fglrx                6179097  0 
-vboxdrv               252228  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
-vboxnetadp             13328  0 
-vboxnetflt             27240  0 
-vboxpci                22911  0 
-wl                   2906597  0
```

Among others, `wl` module is missing, causing the wifi stop working.

Finally, still on `-58`:

```
$ modprobe --list
...output...
updates/dkms/vboxnetflt.ko
updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
updates/dkms/fglrx.ko
updates/dkms/wl.ko
updates/dkms/vboxpci.ko
updates/dkms/vboxnetadp.ko
...output...
```

Any clue to make things to work with kernel `3.2.0-60`?

Comment: Somehow your modules are not being rebuilded for the new kernel.

Comment: I know how to resolve such problem for VirtualBox' and fglrx' modules, but don't know how to resolve it for wl. May be deleting `/var/lib/dkms/<old_kernel_modules>` then reinstalling new kernel help somehow.

Comment: Had a similar problem with nvidia driver and 3.0.60,jockey-gtk did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to rebuild some proprietary drivers. While using `3.2.0-60`, make sure that you have the `linux-headers` with the same version installed. Then open `jockey-gtk` and check if any proprietary drivers are being proposed for the wifi. If it is the case, then try to disable then re-enable the drivers, which will force the system to rebuild them for the kernel that you are currently running.

To see which kernel you're running do:

```
uname -a
```

Comment: Just on a side note, if you have to install the headers, it should run dkms for you. If it doesn't or is the headers are installed, try: `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms $(uname -r)` which runs dkms for everything registered against your running kernel. If there are any errors check out the make.log files in /var/lib/dkms/$drivername/$(uname -r) <--- those aren't real variables on your system, you're going to have to dig a little.

Answer (score 0):

To sure your kernel has been upgraded in correct way you can do these steps.

Strategy : clean up the kernel module and install new version of kernel by PPA.

1- Use following command to pure your kernel:

```
sudo apt-get purge <kernel>
```

2- To know your kernel modules,headers,image you can use search in your cache by following command:

```
sudo apt-cache search <headers,image,...>
```

When you find it you can purge it by first command.

3- And to Upgrade new version of kernel you can use this [link](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) ( PPA repo )

choose your kernel which you want to install it.

**note**: To know your coding of your distribution you can use **sudo lsb_release -a**

**note**: To know current version of your kernel and architecture you can use: **uname -a**

Then you receive ***.deb** files and after checking its checksum you can
move *.deb files to specified folder and run following command:
for example : you can make a directory with this name : kernel by using
**mkdir ~/Desktop/kernel** and move them into it.

Then install them by following command:

```
sudo dpkg --install ~/Desktop/kernel/*.deb
```

then run following command to restart your system:

```
sudo shutdown -r 0
```

I hope it be useful.